# Dynamic Tabs Using Treeview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, treeview, jquery-ui-tabs

I am Developing a Web Application.
 I need Help i have Split the Page into to Two Parts one for TreeView(Menu) and other part to display Menu Pages in Tabs.
So I need help in creating a Treeview Menu with Dynamic Tabs based on the Tree Node Selected. 
Please Help

Comment: Have you tried any thing so far?

Comment: First you need to try it yourself.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/mb-ui/modular-jquery-example). This is an example of single page app with jquery, which implements dynamic tabs based on the Tree node selected by using [jquery-ui Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/)